# Am I able jump to Kohana?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, kohana, hmvc

I'm web developer. I'm using PHP! I don't know how many years of experience I have. Let's say - a few. x) I know object-oriented programming as well. So let me as you a question. =]

**Can I go to Kohana web site, start to read the docs and, after some weeks of learning it, build my 1st web application using Kohana?**

I know that Kohana is HMVC. I don't think that it is big problem, 'couse I just built my own super-simple MVC framework. It's very simple and a few kB's heavy, but I got the idea of MVC. =]

P.S. Just learned basics of PDO too. ^^

Comment: You can build application after few hours of learning it, specially if you are experienced php developer. I jumped into Kohana fast, with no php experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! I've been developing websites as a hobby for only a few years and at work for only half a year. I'm now building my first site using Kohana and it still seems pretty easy.

I must admit I got some experience with other programming languagses, frameworks and design patterns in general, so that might help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

depends, i came from php4 and didn't really touch the level of OOP needed for the php5 kohana framework, i've used classes and functions but the HMVC is a process on it's own to learn, when it comes to Kohana vs YII i'd have to say kohana is easier to pickup.

my only dislike of Kohana is that the documentation is all over the place and outdated and it's not till you try it do you realize you were looking at the version before, ie : 3.0 vs 3.1 is different.. alot.. i'm still getting my head around it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided (and the fact that each person's rate of learning is different), it's pretty impossible to meaningfully answer this question.

However, I'll go for "yes", as Kohana's a fairly compact framework from what I can recall.

That said, the only way you'll actually know is if you try, irrespective of whatever answers you get.

Comment: Thanks for optimistic answer. I will try and I will learn it. For sure. =]

Comment: @daGrevis Hope it goes well. :-)